# Discord.py - Sending to multiple channels

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a working bot that sends posts from my discord server to another. I'm looking for a way to add additional channels of other servers but can't figure out how to get it to work. I read somewhere that `get_channel` only works once and that I need to incorporate it into a loop? I'm new to python and discord.py so most likely I just don't understand. Here's my code, Hopefully, someone can help.

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)
from discord.ext import commands

test001from=1029028218684055562
test001to=1028777554217291806, 1028777583808098304

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".");

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Active")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == test001from:
        channeltosend  = bot.get_channel(test001to)
        await channeltosend.send(message.content)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put all the channel ids into a list like so: `test001to[1028777554217291806, 1028777583808098304]`

Second, use `get_channel` in the `on_ready` function and save them as a new list.

Third, use a for loop to iterate through the new list you created `for chan in channels` and send the message to each channel `chan.send(message.content)`.

Comment: Thanks @Will Codes, Do you have an example of how this should look?

Comment: Still struggling with this one :-(